# Sql select data from two table with different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 table with different column names.

**Table1**

```
alias_id | key | keyword
1          a=1   xx
2          b=1   xxxx
```

**Table2**

```
product_id | store_id
1            1   
2            7
```

I want the query the all `keyword` row from the `table1` where the key `a=1` and in the `table2` the `product_id=1` and `store_id=7.` In the `table1` the `key` column contains like this `key_id=20` but in the `table2` I have a column `product_id` which is contains `20`

I tried a lot of option like `union` and `join`, but somehow don't want to work for me.

Comment: How does the two tables relate? Is it that Table1.alias_id == Table2.product_id ?

Comment: This is my problem, the two table is not related. So I don't know any solution is exist?

Comment: So why do you need to query both tables at once? Basically unions are used to combine result sets http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp and joins to combine tables using a common fields http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp .

Comment: I tried with union. 

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE key LIKE "a=%"
UNION
SELECT store_id FROM table2 WHERE store_id=7

but i get error The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns. 

So need for me query the all keyword, but only when both criteria is exist. at table1 LIKE a=% and at table2 store_id=7 the more query is can be null

Comment: What you want exatly ?! `alias_id` and `product_id` are linking two table together ?

Comment: @Robert, you can't union `*` with `store_id`.  Instead of `*` you can `SELECT alias_id`, assuming it has a compatible type with `product_id`.  But as @Sach said, why not just use two queries if these are separate things?

Comment: Sorry guys i see now this is not was obvious. 

I want the query the all keyword row form the table1 where the key a=|1| and in the table2 product_id=|1| and store_id=7. 

In the table1 the key column contains like this key_id=20 but in the table2 I have a column product_id which is contains 20. I hope now I can explained.

Comment: @Robert, I think it would help to clarify your question if you would describe your expected output.  How many rows are you expecting to get back, how many columns are you expecting and what are the column names you want?

Comment: Fixed formatting and grammar. Please proofread your question before posting it and always add what you have tried to your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are querying two tables without any of the same fields and have a "where clause", use this:

```
WITH query1 as (Select t1.a from t1 where t1.a = 'xxxxx'),
     query2 as (Select t2.b from t2 where t2.b = 'yyyyy')
Select * FROM query1 FULL OUTER JOIN query2 on t1.a <> t2.b
```

Answer (score 0):

According to  your description in comments, try this:

```
select key,keyword from table1 where key='a=1'
union all
select product_id,store_id from table2 where product_id='1' and store_id='7'
```

Answer (score 0):

To use [Union](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) we have to make the two select statement have the same number of columns and the same data types,

> Selected columns listed in corresponding positions of each SELECT
>   statement should have the same data type.

```
select `alias_id`as c1, `key` as c2, `keyword` as c3
from Table1 where `key` LIKE 'a=%'
union all
select `product_id` as c1, CAST(`store_id` as CHAR(4)) as c2, '' as c3 
from Table2 where store_id=7
```

Live [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa9ba/5)

Comment: What does `CAST` in your query ?

Comment: @stack They need to have same data type, even if there is auto cast, I put it to make clear answer.

Comment: Sorry probably i can't explain very well this. 
So only need for me the query if 3 criteria is exist. 

Table1 LIKE a=|1|
Table2 product_id=|1|   store_id=7
Table1 LIKE a=|1| = Table2 product_id=|1|  

And after need for me a row with the keyword. Maybe this is something if statement. Need to query the keyword when all criteria is meets.

Both mentioned solution gave for me back 2 rows.